# How do I scrape/interact with Google Maps to make FloatingSheep-style maps (e.g., # of bars per capita)?

Tags: ruby, maps, screen-scraping

I was looking at this [map of bars vs. grocery stores in each part of the U.S.](http://www.floatingsheep.org/2010/02/beer-belly-of-america.html) on FloatingSheep.org, and noticed they used data from Google Maps directory.

My question is: How do I access the directory to find similar info (e.g., daycares per city, grocery stores per city, etc.)?

I know some Ruby -- enough to scrape certain web pages. I learned from [Dan Nguyen's Bastards Book of Ruby](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/).

If you need me to be more specific or give any more info about what I'm looking for, just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: A few questions: (1)For clarity, do you want to take screenshots of the pages? (2) Will this always run on your local machine? Or you need a solution that will work when deployed to a server?

Comment: 1) Nah, not screenshots. One example I'd like to do is find the number of bars listed in GMaps' directory for each city. So I'm guessing I'd be looking for text which I can interpret into data.      2)For now, the script would run on my local machine.

Comment: Looks like the API is deprecated http://maps.google.com/gadgets/directory?synd=mpl

Comment: Hm, I'd ask if it was still somehow possible to get this data, but I'm guessing the best way to find out would be to ask the Google folks themselves. Thanks for your help.